# Как в Symfony 2 использовать pdo?

Tags: pdo, php, symfony2

Никакой информации не нашел, спрашиваю здесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**здесь**

В Symfony 2 не используется напрямую PDO. Там используются Doctrine или Propel, которые предоставляют высокоуровневую абстракцию над данными. Подробно - в документации http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html